# I want to see if there is anything I don't need in my CSS file for my current layout

Tags: html, css

Here is my link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq7rq/) and the [full screen description](http://jsfiddle.net/zq7rq/embedded/result/).

*Note on the full mode screen*: the footer is not sticking, but it actually sticks if I check on my browser.

So that is exactly what I want for my layout. I want someone to see if there's anything in my CSS I don't need, or if I am using improperly without affecting the layout that is displayed.

For example:

1. Under the Header ID I have a element called top:0; what is this used for and do I actually need it?
2. Under the Main ID I have margin: 0 auto -50px; I found help from someone, but quite don't understand the theory on it.
3. Under the Footer ID I have bottom:0; what is this used for as well and do I need it?

**HTML:**

```
        <body>
                <div id="page">

                        <div id="header">
                        </div>

                        <div id="main">
                        </div>

                        <div id="footer">
                        </div>

                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*THIS IS THE CSS CODE FOR WNG WEBSITE*/
html, body
{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
        font-size:0.8em;
}
#page
{
        height:100%;
        min-width:960px;
}
#header
{
        position:relative;
        background-color:#115EA2;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
}
#main
{
        width:1300px;
        background-color:#F1F2F3;
        margin: 0 auto -50px;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
        color:#115EA2;
        text-decoration:none;
        height:2000px;
}
#footer
{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        height: 35px;
        background-color:#115EA2;
}
```

Comment: Fixed width websites are pretty much a thing of the past thanks to a plethora of mobile and tablet resolutions.  *Responsive design* is the way things are generally done now, even if mobile devices currently make up a relatively small percentage of your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your element is fixed or absolutely positioned, `top: 0` is doing nothing for you (`#header`).  Unless your descendant elements are absolutely positioned (or you need to adjust the element's stacking order due to surrounding absolutely positioned elements), you probably don't need `position: relative` either.

The negative margin on `#main` is doing nothing for you (`margin: 0 auto` gives identical results).  Generally, you use negative margins to nudge things around similar to relative positioning, but where it effects the position of everything that follows as well (eg. an element with `margin-top: -50px` will move up 50px and so will everything below it, but an element that's relatively positioned with a `top: -50px` will only shift *that* element up and not the following elements).

`vertical-align: bottom` isn't doing anything for you either (`#main`).  The vertical-align property only works on inline or table-cell elements.

It's not really a good idea to set fixed heights on elements that will have an unknown amount of content (`#main`).  Scrollbars give users clues as to how much content there is on the page.  It can be confusing to the user when they scroll and scroll, but there's no more content to find.  If the content is longer than you've allowed for, it will spill out of the container or get clipped off (depending on the element's overflow setting).

If you want your footer to be at the bottom of the viewport, then yes, you need `bottom: 0`.

Comment: Thank you tons for all the detailed information!!! I think out of all the help that I have been getting your answer really made it clear. One question I have is about fixed heights. So I want a fixed height for the main content between the header and footer. If I remove height it moves the content div all the way to the header and looks very unprofessional. So what is the best way for me to assign the height to be from the header to the footer and if content needs more room at the bottom it automatically extends with scroll? Any idea how to get that done?

Comment: This question might be better asked on SO, but I usually recommend using an illusion to make you think the element is taller than it really is by setting a background color on an ancestor element.  If you need it to work without an illusion, there are ways to do so using `display: table|table-row`:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/8ocxwfbk